# Authorize a parameter for an action in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I commonly need to authorize a particular parameter to be evaluated in a service call within an action in MVC5. For instance, let's say that my action is `public ActionResult Edit(string partnerName)`.

Today, I handle this by always evaluating `if (!User.CanAccessPartnerModule(THIS_MODULE_ID, partnerName)) throw new UnauthorizedException();`

However, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = THIS_MODULE_ID)]
public ActionResult Edit([AuthorizePartnerModule(THIS_MODULE_ID)] string partnerName)
{
    ...
}
```

To be clear, 1) I don't think the `AuthorizeAttribute` would be necessary if this were implemented as I envision, and 2) the thing that doesn't exist is the `AuthorizePartnerModuleAttribute`.

Is there a ready-made attribute or tutorial that explains how this may be accomplished? And if not, is this not advisable to do?

Comment: Yes this is possible by overriding the `Authorize` attribute. If you don't get an answer by tomorrow I'll post some code for this specific issue.

Comment: @Shoe thanks ... I wasn't aware `AuthorizeAttribute` applied to parameters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend authorization with a custom authorization filter by creating a subclass of **AuthorizeAttribute**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Filters 
{
     public class AuthorizePartnerModule : AuthorizeAttribute 
     {
         protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
         {
             // getting the parameter from the request
            string partnerName = httpContext.Request.Params["groupId"].ToString();

            // custom validation
            return User.CanAccessPartnerModule(THIS_MODULE_ID, partnerName);
         }
     }
}
```

And then, you could validate your action method with:

```
[AuthorizePartnerModule(Roles = THIS_MODULE_ID)]
public ActionResult Edit(string partnerName)
{
    ...
}
```

Another option would be to create a custom **ActionFilter** (an implementation of **IActionFilter**). An ActionFilter  implements two methods:

- **OnActionExecuting** is executed right before the action method
- **OnActionExecuted** is executed right after the action method execution.

So, you could make the necessary validation with something like:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Filters {
     public class AuthorizePartnerModule : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter 
     {

         public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
         {
            // getting the parameter from the request
            string partnerName = filterContext.ActionParameters["partnerName"].ToString();

            // custom validation
            if (!User.CanAccessPartnerModule(THIS_MODULE_ID, partnerName)) 
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
            }
         }

         public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
         {
             // do nothing
         }
     }
}
```

In this case, however ,you would have to validate like that:

```
[Authorize(Roles = THIS_MODULE_ID)]
[AuthorizePartnerModule]
public ActionResult Edit(string partnerName)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will give it a spin today.